# When to load data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm using a cocoa pod called [ACTabScrollView](https://github.com/azurechen/ACTabScrollView). In the demo code, it has a View Controller for the UI part which scrolls from side to side and has different tabs, and a view controller that has a table view (a "content view controller"). Each tab displays different information on each table view, but the information is sourced from a single array and is divided via an assigned enum. If this is confusing, there is a gif on the ACTabScrollView readme. In my "content view controller," I can hard code an array and it works flawlessly. The class for this content view controller has a variable declaration that I've never seen before as I'm new to iOS programming.

```
var category: TeamCategory? {
    didSet {
        for team in Team.teamArray {
            if (team.category == category || category == .all) {
                teamArray.append(team)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A project sample with this snippet is located [here](https://github.com/azurechen/ACTabScrollView/blob/master/ACTabScrollView/ContentViewController.swift).

In the above snippet, Team is a model of teams, and the class has a hard coded array of teams (which are structs).

Obviously, I don't want to hard code the array of Teams in the app because I want to be able to update the array and have it update in real time. I'm using Firebase and I've tried loading the array in the App Delegate, in the UI view controller, and in the content view controller, but the tableView does not populate. I've confirmed that the data is arriving.

When/Where should I load the data from Firebase? The content view controller needs the array loaded before the view controller is loaded. Any tips for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData` on the table view after you update your data model with the data from Firebase?

Comment: First: try to add `teamArray = []` before entering the for loop,   Second: You can try to add a boolean variable, with a didSet that activates/deactivate a UIActivityView (progress indicator),   Third: Like @rmaddy says, use `reloadData` in the end of your didSet that you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you should load the data from Firebase is a design decision. You said that the content view controller needs to have the array loaded before the view controller is loaded, so you should request that data from Firebase at some point in your app flow where you can be guaranteed that the request will have come back with data before your TableView is attempting to load that data.

You may be running into a race condition where you are requesting the data, and then going to the content view controller before the request finished.

In general you don't want to have to rely on a guarantee that a request will finish in time, so I recommend doing what @rmaddy suggested, where you load the data before hand, and then have some sort of completion handler / notification / delegate call that will call `reloadData` on your tableView once the array from which you are pulling your data is updated.

The project sample you are referring to does not handle an asynchronous case, as you are handling. The `didSet` in the property declaration is just a closure that gets executed when you set a value for that property. In the case of the project sample, the news category is set at the time of the view controller instantiation, and then the `didSet` executes once and attaches the appropriate news array for the tableView to access. Again, in your case, as long as you are updating your array that contains your tableview's source of data after the data returns from Firebase, calling `reloadData` on your tableView should achieve the result you are looking for. If it doesn't, then that means you aren't properly updating that `teamArray`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I apologize for the very late reply. The issue came down to a couple things, mainly I wasn't reloading my tableView every time I added a new team to the array. My next question is related to the didSet. Is there a way for me to call this once the array is completely loaded? As it is now, it is called right when the view controller is instantiated but the array is empty at that time.